# TypeError: get_channel() missing 1 required positional argument: 'id' channell

Tags: discord, discord.py

пытаюсь сделать отправление сообщении при включении бота в Cogs, но у меня возникает эта ошибка.

Код:

```
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('loaded')
        channel = client.get_channel(906168716197232660)
        await channel.send(embed = discord.Embed(title=f'Бот был включен!', description='Ранее было написано. почему бот был выключен. Надеюсь.', color=0x1f8b4c))

        embed1 = discord.Embed(title='Бот был включен!', description='Данное сообщение будет автоматически удалено через 5 секунд....')
        embed1.add_field(name='Обновления / Версия / Сервер', value='**Обновления**: \nК сожалению, на данный момент нету никаких обновлений. Но происходит уменьшение кода в main.py. \n\n**Версия**: \nНа данный момент версия бота: **2.0.1**. \n\n**Дискорд Сервер Бота**: Можно найти в **ОБОТЕ**')
        channel1 = client.get_channel(906998823187017728)
        await channel1.send(embed=embed1, delete_after=5)

        while True:
            await self.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.listening, name=f"за чтением"))
            await s(10)# 10 as in 10seconds
            await self.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name="в спидран по lib.размер"))
            await s(10)
            await self.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.competing, name=f"в чистоте"))
            await s(10)
            await self.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=self.discord.ActivityType.streaming, name=f"разработчиков"))
            await s(10)
            await self.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name=f"на тебя <3"))
```

А так-же ошибка:

```
Ignoring exception in on_ready
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/runner/VioletElectronicRadius/cogs/events maybe.py", line 41, in on_ready
    channel = client.get_channel(906168716197232660)
TypeError: get_channel() missing 1 required positional argument: 'id'
172.18.0.1 - - [28/Nov/2021 12:03:12] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Answer (score 0):

В [доках](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/cogs.html) подробно написано, как использовать коги

Если у вас `client` это объект бота, то:

```
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('loaded')
        channel = self.client.get_channel(906168716197232660)
        await channel.send(embed = discord.Embed(title=f'Бот был включен!', description='Ранее было написано. почему бот был выключен. Надеюсь.', color=0x1f8b4c))

        embed1 = discord.Embed(title='Бот был включен!', description='Данное сообщение будет автоматически удалено через 5 секунд....')
        embed1.add_field(name='Обновления / Версия / Сервер', value='**Обновления**: \nК сожалению, на данный момент нету никаких обновлений. Но происходит уменьшение кода в main.py. \n\n**Версия**: \nНа данный момент версия бота: **2.0.1**. \n\n**Дискорд Сервер Бота**: Можно найти в **ОБОТЕ**')
        channel1 = self.client.get_channel(906998823187017728)
        await channel1.send(embed=embed1, delete_after=5)
    ...
```

Comment: К сожалению у меня до сих пор осталась данная ошибка.

Comment: Скиньте вес ког, исправив ваш запрос. Где ошибка?